# In MFC RegisterHotKey function don't respond

Tags: winapi, mfc

In MFC RegisterHotKey function don't respond from Dll but works fine if i put same code in exe.
i am using same code which works in exe and putting it in Dll.
Also making sure that Dll gets load and othere changes are reflecting when i run exe.

Comment: Could you please show how you are using the function from dll? A handle to the window that will receive WM_HOTKEY messages generated by the hot key - what you are passing into it

Comment: RegisterHotKey(GetSafeHwnd(), GlobalAddAtom("CTRL+D"), MOD_CONTROL, 'D');

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same code for registering a hotkey in your DLL as in your EXE. This is your problem. See documentation for [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx):

> An application must specify an id value in the range 0x0000 through 0xBFFF. **A shared DLL must specify a value in the range 0xC000 through 0xFFFF** (the range returned by the [**GlobalAddAtom**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649060.aspx) function). To avoid conflicts with hot-key identifiers defined by other shared DLLs, a DLL should use the **GlobalAddAtom** function to obtain the hot-key identifier.

To use `RegisterHotKey` from a shared DLL, you need to generate an *id* value. To get a value in the correct range, call `GlobalAddAtom` with a string parameter (see [About Atom Tables: String Atoms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053.aspx#_win32_String_Atoms)). To create a unique id, pass the string representation of a GUID.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Same code means , i am commenting out code in exe and using that code in Dll . so its not duplicate code. only one RegisterHotKey is there in whole application

Comment: @raje1987: The problem isn't, that the same code is present. The problem is your use of the **wrong id range**, when copying the code over to the DLL (see text in **bold** in the quoted reference documentation).

Comment: i tried using GlobalAddAtom  in Dll too. but it still wont work

Answer (score 0):

```
// Putting in message map 
ON_MESSAGE(WM_HOTKEY, OnHotKey)

//Demographic Bar HotKey (putting in create or init)
RegisterHotKey(GetSafeHwnd(), GlobalAddAtom("SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+D"), MOD_SHIFT | MOD_CONTROL | MOD_ALT, 'D');

//source file 
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnHotKey(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int hotKeyId = (int)wParam;
    CString atomName;
    GlobalGetAtomName(hotKeyId, atomName.GetBuffer(20), 20);
    atomName.ReleaseBuffer();

    if (atomName.Compare("SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+D") == 0)
    {
        SetPaneFocused(1);  //Hard-coding 1 & 2 as place holders.  Actual pane id should be here
    }
    else if (atomName.Compare("SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+M") == 0)
    {
        SetPaneFocused(2);
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```